# C++ app built on Windows 7 (using VS2010 IDE and VS2008 toolset) runs on Windows 7, but not on Win XP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp

I have a C++ application, which is built on Windows 7 using VS 2010 IDE against VS2008 toolset. I have verified that it depends on msvc*90.dll.

The problem occurs when i move it to XP professional SP3 machine. I have installed the 32-bit vs 2008 redistributable package too.

However, the application fails to run. No error is reported. Nothing is logged into system even viewer as well.

Any hints?

PS: I have seen the following threads already.

- [Program Built on Win7 won't run on WinXP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311754/program-built-on-win7-wont-run-on-winxp)
- [How do I compile for windows XP under windows 7 / visual studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581752/how-do-i-compile-for-windows-xp-under-windows-7-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the correct VS2008 redistributable package?  As I noted in [this answer for VS2005](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12527449/292432), there are lots of them.

Comment: What are WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT defined to be in your build? If they exceed 0x0501 (or 0x0502 for XPSP2) you may be using unsupported or unimplemented OS features without even knowing it.

Comment: I tried with setting the above to macros to 0x0501, and still it fails.

Comment: I also tried building the app on Win XP SP3 with VS 2010 (using VS2008 toolset). Still the same problem.

Comment: You need to start putting in exits early in the program and see how far you can go. Make sure to print and flush something just before the exit call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved now. The problem was not related to dependencies. Instead, it was some directory not existing in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the DLL in that Windows XP system with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). This may help you find if you are not missing another dependency or not dealing with side by side execution problems.

Comment: The dependency walker on XP says: "Error opening file. The system cannot find the specified file" for the below two dlls
IESHIMS.DLL
WER.DLL

Comment: Not that i would try to propose a solution but -"Ieshims.dll and wer.dll are only used on Vista and above machines for IE8, they are not needed in XP and thats why you can't find them." And you can download them from http://www.dll-files.com/.